# Flexslider not resizing properly

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I use Flexslider on my website. But when I resize my screen or rotate my mobile phone, Flexslider is do not resize the slider properly.

I saw the docs from Woothemes, with the grid function, but it doesn't work for 100%. Does someone know why?

My flexslider function looks like this:

```
flexslider = { vars:{} };

startLogos = function(){
    $('.logos .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 200,
        itemMargin: 20,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: false,
        minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
        maxItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
        start: function(slider){
            flexslider = slider;
        }
    });
};
```

My grid looks like this:

```
getGridSize = function() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 1 :
           (window.innerWidth < 768) ? 2 :
           (window.innerWidth < 1024) ? 3 : 4; 
}
```

I have a variable:

```
var $window = $(window)
```

Of course on a $window.load I call the startLogos function and on a $window.resize I call it again.

When I test this on a iPad in Safari, it works great! Everything works fine, but on a desktop browser and a Android device.. (grr!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfect for me.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       var slider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider');   
       slider.resize();
   }, 500); 
});
```